# Tried to utilize azure windows 2012 R2 virtual machine mysql but I can't access it

Tags: mysql, azure, virtual-machine

I recently got interested in utilizing a bunch of VM that I have access to and I come to a conclusion that windows server R2 2012 was the easiest to start with. I was able to remotely connect to it, no problem I manage to install MySQL server and IIS where I am able to see it on localhost.

Here is how the IIS looks like

and here is the localhost database from the VM

```
grant all privileges on *.* 'USERNAME'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

[image]

I figured out that I needed to grant privileges to users and ip's as well. However, whenever I try to connect it outside the machine, with the IP or DNS it just gives me an error. What am I doing wrong? Since clearly the VM visibility is the issue here.

Here is the firewall and azure firewall

[image]

And whenever I try to connect with the following

```
hostname: dns or ip from the VM on azure
```

(I haven't tried the nettworks adresse that you get from azure, but not sure really which to use )

```
port:3306
```

I get a nasty cannot connect to with, basically I don't its not visiable and how do I make it visable to other machines/devices/apps

Comment: Do you use *.cloudapp.net for connecting, right?

Comment: Yes, did the whatevernameiset.cloudapp.net with port 3306 which I choose during the installition of MYSQL oracle

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the issue should be somewhere in the settings. Firstly, could you check if you can connect to the MySQL from the inside of the VM?

Please make sure that you done all of the needed configuration actions. You may refer to the [official guidance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-sql-connect/) (it is for SQL Server, so avoid the SQL Server relevant bullets) - you should end with that list:

> Create a TCP endpoint for the virtual machine
>
> Open TCP ports in the Windows firewall

You shown the first one configuration, so what is left to configure is the Windows firewall.

Comment: http://imgur.com/n3JjXvB Yes as you can see this is what shows the function that I did querry on here I used the % on IP and added 2 users which are in the dB, aswell as ROOT

Comment: @MikeBroski could you try to add the same 3306 for outbound or disable the Windows Server firewall for a time?

Comment: I changed the inbound connections to Allow they were not allowed I'l disable the firewall, I'm guessing my azure firewall is the problem got any ideas how I should set it up? I have no clue

Comment: OMG I got a small breakthrough after I disabled the firewall, i got a diffrent error, now it says no administartion nonesene when I log in

Comment: A little step forward... let's connect to the MySQL then enable firewall and other stuff one by one. What is the exact error? Could you try another workaround provided here? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/create-your-own-dedicated-mysql-server-for-your-azure-websites/ > GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' > IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: Here is the error I get http://imgur.com/FRcjdzE and I get a cannot connect to mysql when I try test connection.  This is the grants for root http://imgur.com/Y6mrH40 and here is the that spefic user I use http://imgur.com/MXbEGlC

Comment: @MikeBroski Ugh. Did you try something else to connect? Like a MySQL command line. I did not use the Workbench, but that WMI error scares me.